# Scrollbar in parent only (no child scrollbars)

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel, flowlayoutpanel

I have a nested structure of panels. A parent (Tablelayoutpanel) contains several different panels in vertical order. In there I have Child Panels (Flowlayoutpanel) providing a horizontal sequence of controls.
What happens now is that I have horizontal scrollbars in my child panels. All child panels have the same width and structure. I would like to have only the scrollbars in my parent panel and these scrollbars move the content inside all children synchronously.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWgB2.png)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you also use `Flowlayoutpanel` as a parent by disabling the `AutoScroll` property and changing the fill orientation?